# Background image hyper link for an empty div tag

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background-image

In my website i have a empty `<div>` with `background-image`. my `<div>` **width** is **280px** and `background-image` **width** is **165px**. So i need the link only in **165px**(only for `background-image`). Is it possible to give like that ?

[image]

Here, `border` `black` is my `<div>` and **READ MORE** is my `background-image`.

**Note:** If i am using `<img>` tag directly inside `<div>` tag instead of using as a `background-image` , then my problem is solved. But I want to know whether is it possible to give `background-image` as a link for an empty `<div>` ?

Comment: put a empty <a> tag & position its accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @SVS for your valuable answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. Place an empty 'A' tag over the background image.
2. Use an 'A' tag and place the image as the background-image of the 'A' tag.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but in this case i tried the `<a>` tag also, i need the exact link for the background.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'you need the exact link for the background'? Can you elaborate?

Comment: yea sure, i need the link which should be match with images shape. The link should exist inside the image only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this

```
#box-link { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 8px; /*what ever*/
        left: 20px;  /*what ever*/
        width: 83px; /*what ever*/
        height: 83px; /*what ever*/
        background-color: transparent; 
        border: 1px solid yellow; /*what ever*/
}   



        <div class="box1">
        <a id="box-link" href="#"></a>
        </p>
        </div>
```

try this link

http://www.position-relative.com/tutorials/tute1_css_bg_image.php

Answer (score 0):

No, you cann`t do link from background-image. But you can emulate : add to main div position:relative, and inside it add div ( with position: absolute and background:0 ) to place ,where you want link.

Answer (score -1):

you need to give the height and width for the a tag.

```
a{
    background:red;
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
    display:block;
}
```

- height and width as per your image size

refer http://jsfiddle.net/3se2E/